# LIBSVM: Get support vectors from model file

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

This may be a weird request so some explanation first. I recently had a sudden hd crash and lost a data file I was using to generate model files with libSVM. I do have the SVM model and scaling file that I generated from this data file and I was wondering if there is a way to generate a data file from the Support Vectors in the model file, something like `model_sv_to_instances(model, &instances)` since thhe process for obtaining instances is very costly. (I know it won't be the same as the original but still it's better than nothing) I'm using a probabilistic SVM with  RBF kernel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you open a given model file in any text editor you would find something like this:

```
 svm_type c_svc
 kernel_type sigmoid
 gamma 0.5
 coef0 0
 nr_class 2
 total_sv 4
 rho 0
 label 0 1
 nr_sv 2 2
 SV
 1 1:0 2:0
 1 1:1 2:1
 -1 1:1 2:0
 -1 1:0 2:1
```

Where the interesting thing for you is after the line with SV.

```
 1 1:0 2:0
 1 1:1 2:1
-1 1:1 2:0
-1 1:0 2:1
```

Those are data points that were selected as support vectors, so you just have to parse the file. The format is as follows : 
[label] [index1]:[value1] [index2]:[value2] ... [indexn][valuen]

For instance, from my example you can conclude that my training set was:

```
x y desired val 
0 0     -1
0 1      1
1 0      1
1 1     -1
```

A few considerations and warnings. The ratio between number of SVs and data points depends on the parameters that you used. In some cases the ratio is big and you would have very few SVs in comparison with your data.

Another thing to keep in mind is that this reduction is likely to change the problem and if you train again just with SVs as data points you would probably get a complete different model with a complete different set of parameters.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I guess the SV is scaled so I will have to "unscale" it to get the real point again?

Comment: @vseguip If you scaled it beforehand... yes you will need to unscale them. The library doesn't scale them automatically though, so it would depend on how you built the model.

Comment: Also, you should take note of this small caveat: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f430 (the `label` line in the model file is really, really important). On the other hand, you should always have a backup for such tings. Dropbox works great, for example.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, SVM models in general, and libSVM models in particular, consist of only the support vectors. These vectors represent the borderline between the classes; most probably, they don't represent the vast majority of your data points. So, unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to regenerate your data from the model.

Having said that, I can think of an esoteric case where there might be some value to the model: there are companies specializing in recovering data in such cases (e.g. from crashed HDs). However, the recovered data sometimes has gaps; in certain cases, the model might be reverse-engineered to fill-in some missing spots. However, this is very theoretic.

EDIT: as the other answers state, the proportion of data points represented by the support vectors might vary, depending on the specific problem and parameters. However, as stated above, in most common cases, you'll be able to reconstruct only a small fraction of your original data set.

Comment: "These vectors represent the borderline between the classes; it doesn't directly reference any specific data point" You are right except that the support vectors does directly relate with the training set since they are the data points that define the hyperplane that separates the classes.

Comment: "Fortunately" the model is pretty big so even with that caveat I will be able to recover a fair share of the data.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `RBF` you are lucky. According to the [libsvm FAQ](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f402) you can extract the support vectors from the model file:

> In the model file, after parameters and other informations such as labels , each line represents a support vector.

But remember, these are only the support vectors, which are only a fraction of your original input data.